# Trying to query a workbook in a sharepoint site

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a workbook from a sharepoint site, and i'm a bit confused by the api. I could get it working using something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveId/root:/path/test.xlsx
```

which is fine if it's in a OneDrive, but I need to grab a different file from the sites. I was able to query the site using `sites/root:/SiteName` But when I try to get the drive of the site using the following query I get an error about an invalid Url.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/SiteName:/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook
```

Are files in a sharepoint site's Document section not stored in a drive? How do you access those files otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to do it in two queries.

First you query to get the siteId:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/<siteName>
```

Then once you have the siteId you can get the workbook with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteId>/drive/root:/<pathToWorkbook>:/workbook
```